# Как синхронизировать тёмную тему для всех страниц

Tags: javascript, html, css

Например у меня есть "index1.html" и "index2.html" и мне нужно синхронизировать тёмную тему для этих страниц.

Вот код на js

```js
toggleThemeBtn.onclick = () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark")
    toggleThemeBtn.innerText = document.body.classList.contains("dark") ? "Светлая тема" : "Тёмная тема"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно хранить информацию о выбранной теме в `localStorage`. Например:

```
if(document.body.classList.toggle("dark")){
  localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
}else{
  localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
}
```

Потом, чтобы узнать какая тема выбрана у пользователя нужно просто обратиться к `localStorage`. Например:

```
var theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
```

или

```
var theme = localStorage.theme;
```